# Migrating Azure function written in java to AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, migration

As a move to cloud initiative I need to migrate my application which is an azure function written in java inserting values to a Cosmosdb to AWS platform, I need to move the azure function to an AWS Lambda and we would use document Db/Mongodb as the database for storing the values.
Please provide any simple way to implement this. Thanks in advance.

I am estimating the changes required. Need help with the process for it

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way to port Azure Java code to an AWS Lambda function. The way to perform this is to create a new AWS Lambda project that uses the [Java runtime API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/handlers/RequestHandler.html).

Once you create the project, you can build the business logic to meet your business goals. If you do not know how to program an AWS Lambda function that uses the Lambda Java API, then look at this example that builds a Lambda function that can detect PPE.

[Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe)

By following this example, you will gain an understanding of how to code an AWS Lambda function using the Java Lambda API. This example also show how to persist data into an Amazon DynamoDB table.